# Location Service [ Access ] Enable Listener

Tags: java, android

Is there a some way to register a listener to Location Service, so that when the user enable them in the setting application is notified about it ?

The issue i face is that, i show the user with Alert Dialog to enable location access, usual flow is like, user will click on [Enable] positive response, however elite users many don't go through such a flow and directly enable location access manually via going to settings. Issue with indirect flow is that, i'm unable to dismiss the dialog. A logical solution is the activity listening to location access enable event. Is there way to register a listener like that ?

Another not so neat way to is to dismiss the dialog in the call back

```
@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // check if instantiated 
            if (enableLocationAccessAlert != null) {
                enableLocationAccessAlert.dismissDialog();
            }

            findAddressPositionCamera(location);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is already supported through these functions when you implements `LocationListener`:

```
@Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // Called when the provider is disabled by the user. If requestLocationUpdates is called on an already disabled provider, this method is called immediately.

    }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // Called when the provider is enabled by the user.

}



@Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // Called when the provider status changes. This method is called when a provider is unable to fetch a location or if the provider has recently become available after a period of unavailability.

    }
```

You just need to use these to keep track of the `Location Service` status.
Hope this helps.